# URL contains "?" mark,the url redirect not working in Magento Enterprise1.13

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, url-rewrite

I have some issue in URL redirecting. I've created a url redirect (in admin) without quotation and it's working fine. **Example:** `http//www.domain.com/products/wingback-chair/leadimage.position=3`

when ever I create a url redirect (in admin) with quotation mark like
`http//www.domain.com/products/wingback-chair?leadimage.position=3` the URL redirect does not work.it's shows 404 error.

Please tell me if there any possibilities via htacces convert "?" to "/" or any idea/suggestion. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .htaccess for a few specific redirects, like if you want to redirect `/page.php?id=4` to `http://example.org/page/4` add the following lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/page/%1.pdf [R=302,L]
```